# What's the difference between 震う (ふるう) and 震える (ふるえる)?

Tags: word-choice

On my kanji dictionary, they have the same translation. I don't understand if there's any difference. As usual.

Comment: The 1st [Google Search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E9%9C%87%E3%81%86+%E9%9C%87%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) seems [relevant](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/526704).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, 震う is an old form of 震える with the same meaning. Such uses of 震う are found in the literature of Meiji Era as 身体のぶるぶると震う, おののき震うと同じ状なり, 袋を持った手がガチガチと震う, and 肩の震うばかり胸にこたえた, all of which sound old-fashioned to us. But it seems to me that there are some exceptional uses of 震う in Modern Japanese. For example, 震っている can be said to have derived from 震う, while 震えている is also used in daily conversation.

Comment: Doesn't 震っている sound old too?

Comment: Sorry I am late in answering your question. 震えている and 震っている never sound old and are used in daily speech. The latter is, rather, more colloquial or informal because of  っ in this word.